# How to say "Don't treat me coldly"?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

I know that if I want to say "You're cold!" I can just say "つめたい！"

But is there a way of saying "Please don't be cold to me"?

The whole context is truly too long to put into this question but basically I would like to know how to ask

> Did you tell XY to not be cold to me?

Comment: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%86%B7%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84&ref=sa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the appropriate expression  for "please don't be cold to me" may depend on the situation.

One possibility is "お手{て}柔{やわ}らかに" which means "please do not be harsh on me."

Or you can say "冷{つめ}たくしないでよ" if you prefer more straight (= non euphemistic) expression.

And for "did you tell XY to not be cold to me?" I would say "私{わたし}に冷{つめ}たくしないように、XYに言{い}ってくれた？"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25690/discussion-on-answer-by-eltonjohn-how-to-say-dont-treat-me-coldly).